# Syntax error in UPDATE statement with c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, sql-update, syntax-error

I have created a software by MS Access but if I want to update row in table showing error `Syntax error in UPDATE statement.`

This is my code.

```
string cmdString = "UPDATE users SET username=@username,password=@password,email=@email WHERE ID=@ID";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[3].Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer, 100).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
cmd.CommandText = cmdString;
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Is that all of the error message? Can you show the resulting update-statement string?

Comment: Sorry , this code for update date in row in table

Comment: I thought either Access or OLE DB didn't support named parameters.  See [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters#remarks): "The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used."

Comment: I changed the table name from users to user_table but the message error showing :\

Comment: i used the question mark but the error is showing

Comment: `string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\mydb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
            con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand()`

Comment: the connection is Running at good

Comment: No, i open the connection in Form_Load and getting data from table this is Running at good but if i want to Update data show this error

Comment: my Brother , the connection is saved in `con` variable and we can get set and update without con.Close();

Comment: Excelent, for this we don't need to close the connection and open if we want to do any process

Comment: and if error in connection will tell me the connection is open

Comment: can you help me :)

Comment: @MK.DEVELOPER To be clear, it is good practice and takes [minimal code](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to close the connection when you are done using it, but that's not the issue here.  Also, can you edit some of this information/code from your comments into the question?  This comments section has gotten mighty cluttered...

Comment: Ok , will change the code in question.

Comment: you can read code from this Link [link]http://rextester.com/UZFZ91025

Comment: Thank for all :) the problem is solved by change update statement to        UPDATE user_table SET [username]=@username,[password]=@password,[email]=@email WHERE [ID]=@ID                            thank for all